# How do I drop a sublist containing a certain element from a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists:

```
a = {{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}};
b = {11, 8, 13};
```

I'm looking for a clean way to drop all elements of `a` which contain an element from `b`. The desired output for this example would be

> `c = {{4, 5, 6}}`

where `a[[2]]` and `a[[3]]` have been dropped because they contain elements 8 and 11 from b.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `c=DeleteCases[a, lis_ /; MemberQ[lis, Alternatives @@ b]]`...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! If you post this as a solution I'd love to give you credit. :)

Comment: Don't worry about it, but thanks for sentiment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = {{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {1, 2, 3}, {11, 12, 13}};
b = {11, 8, 13};

Select[a, DisjointQ[b, #] &]

Select[a, {} == b ⋂ # &]
```

> ```
> {{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}}
>
> {{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}}
> ```

[`DisjointQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisjointQ.html) introduced in *Mathematica* 10.  Use the second line in earlier versions.

---

Actually the second line appears to be faster in every test I have performed so I would use it regardless of version.  For example:

```
SeedRandom[1]

a = RandomInteger[999, {5000, 100}];
b = {11, 8, 13};

Select[a, DisjointQ[b, #] &]  // Length // RepeatedTiming

Select[a, {} == b ⋂ # &]      // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.11, 3686}
>
> {0.0286, 3686}
> ```

In this particular case using [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) falls somewhere in the middle:

```
Select[a, FreeQ[Alternatives @@ b]] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0463, 3686}
> ```

Due to its early exit behavior in a case where *most* of the lists will be rejected it pulls ahead:

```
SeedRandom[1]

a = RandomInteger[99, {5000, 100}];

Select[a, {} == b ⋂ # &]             // Length // RepeatedTiming
Select[a, FreeQ[Alternatives @@ b]]  // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0291, 223}
>
> {0.0247, 223}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

ciao doesn't want to make the effort to write an answer, but it is better for a question to have an real answer than a comment answer, so here is his answer.

```
a = {{4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}, {1, 2, 3}, {11, 12, 13}};
b = {11, 8, 13};
DeleteCases[a, lis_List /; MemberQ[lis, Alternatives @@ b]]
```

> `{{4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3}}`

Comment: "ciao doesn't want to make the effort ...". Ouch, man, just ouch...

Comment: @ciao. Sorry that it hurts, but is it not the simple truth?

Comment: @ciao. I'll delete this answer if you would prefer to see it gone now that Mr.Wizard has answered